# Tensorboard: Why does validation loss get evaluated after training loss stops?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, optimal-stopping

When I monitor my model through Tensorboard, I notice that Tensorboard stops plotting the training loss but not the validation loss. Since the early stopping module, as I set it up below, is monitoring the validation loss, shouldn't the training loss get plotted anyhow? The chart is for one of the coordinates I'm predicting. Thank you in advance!

[image: tensorboard]

```
cpp_u = os.path.join(path, r'cp_u')
tbp_t = os.path.join(path, r'tb_t')
tbp_u = os.path.join(path, r'tb_u')

early_stop = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=10, verbose=0, 
                                              mode='auto', restore_best_weights=True)
cp_t = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(cpp_t, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, 
                                                 save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq = 'epoch')
cp_u = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(cpp_u, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, 
                                                 save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', save_freq = 'epoch')
tb_t = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=tbp_t, write_graph=True, write_images=True, histogram_freq=1)
tb_u = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=tbp_u, write_graph=True, write_images=True, histogram_freq=1)

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=True)
batch_size = 384
epochs = 500

def gen_mod(width, opt, w_mult = 12, layer_ratio = 1, alpha = 0.0001, dropout = 0.00, l1 = 0.0000001, l2 = 0.000001,
           kernel_init = tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal()):

    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = width)
    i = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)

    #first hidden layer
    width *= w_mult
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(width, kernel_initializer=kernel_init, use_bias=True)(i)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha)(nn0)
    #nn0 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(nn0)

    #second
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(np.int(width * layer_ratio), kernel_initializer=kernel_init, use_bias = True)(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha)(nn0)
    #nn0 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(nn0)

    #Third
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(np.int(width * layer_ratio**2), kernel_initializer=kernel_init, use_bias = True)(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha)(nn0)
    #nn0 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(nn0)

    #Fourth
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(np.int(width * layer_ratio**3), kernel_initializer=kernel_init, use_bias = True)(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha)(nn0)
    #nn0 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(nn0)

    #Fifth
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(np.int(width * layer_ratio**4), kernel_initializer=kernel_init, use_bias = True)(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha)(nn0)
    #nn0 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(nn0)
    nn0 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(nn0)

    output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha), 
                                   kernel_initializer=kernel_init, use_bias=True, 
                                   kernel_regularizer=reg.l1_l2(l1=l1, l2=l2))(nn0)
    output = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout)(output)

    mod = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output)

    mod.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=opt, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])

    return mod

start_time = time.time()
mod_t = KerasRegressor(build_fn = gen_mod, width = X.shape[2], opt = opt, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.1, 
                       shuffle = True, verbose=0, initial_epoch=0, callbacks = [early_stop, cp_t, tb_t])
mod_u = KerasRegressor(build_fn = gen_mod, width = X.shape[2], opt = opt, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_split=0.1,
                       shuffle = True, verbose=0, initial_epoch=0, callbacks = [early_stop, cp_u, tb_u])

mod = [mod_t, mod_u]
mod = graphs(X, y, model = mod, resid = resid, test_ratio = 0.2, random_state = 42)
execution_time = time.time() - start_time
print('Execution duration (s): %f' %execution_time)

mod[0].model.save(os.path.join(path, r'deep_regr_t.h5'))
mod[2].model.save(os.path.join(path, r'deep_regr_u.h5'))
```